# Import is not working in uploading bulk data with strapi plugin [strapi-plugin-import-export-entries]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, postman, strapi

I am trying to upload json file with strapi plugin "strapi-plugin-import-export-entries" and its giving me this error

```
error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')
at getModelAttributes (backend/node_modules/strapi-plugin-import-export- 
entries/server/utils/models.js:89:46)
```

Environment I have:

```
Macbook Air 2020
Node v16.19.0
"strapi-plugin-import-export-entries": "^1.18.0"
```

The database schema is exactly same as the data I am uploading, I double checked the entries datatype but still its not working, I cloned project again, clean build folder, removed cache folder, updated strapi to latest but still its not fixed.